# Controlling the switching test (behavior) of 6 relays

Tags: python, pyqt5

My GUI should be able to manage testing of relays. The relays (let say 6) are connected to test equipment with appropriate load, and they are turned on and off all the time until one or more relays are failing. The program should stop the test and displays how many switching have been carried out until the defects appeared.

The screenshot of the controller block is given below.

[image]

After starting the test, it waits one second for turning on of the relays to see if the contact are closed and 9 seconds for turning off to see whether the contacts are open again.

I tried using threading in PyQt5 due not to freeze the GUI when I run the test process.
After I got some hints, I tried to rewrite my code without threading.
Below is the code which functions very good as I wanted.

However, I was told that we need a QThread for running the test, because starting the test (turn on/off the relays and sending signals to GPIOs of the hardware) and waiting for the answer (getting response from the GPIOs of the hardware) if they are switching well, needs time about 1 resp. 9 seconds, which freezes the GUI when I run the test in the same thread as the GUI thread.

I'm not so familiar with threading and don't know how to handle this problem with or without threading.

With the provided code below, I don't know due to my task description whether my GUI freezes or not without threading. This is because our hardware is still not ready to make a run to see whether it freezes or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Filename: test_pyqt_signals_with_timer.py
###########################################
# coding: utf-8
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

ACTIVE_WIDTH = 106
ACTIVE_HEIGHT = 32

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.move(100, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test PYQT Signals")

        # self.labels[0].setText('10')
        # self.labels[1].setText('100')
        # self.labels[2].setText('1000')

        self.startCounting = False

        self.createMainWindow()

    ###################################################################

    def createMainWindow(self):

        # Create Vertival layout for three Horizontal laouts
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)         # Create Vertical Layout
        self.h_layout_1 = QHBoxLayout(self)     # Create Horizontal Layout for Top Row

        self.btnStartAll = QPushButton()
        self.btnStartAll.setText("Start All")
        self.btnStartAll.setObjectName("btnStartAll")
        self.btnStartAll.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
        self.btnStartAll.clicked.connect(self.start_all)
        self.btnStartAll.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; '
            'font-size: 13pt; '
            'color: blue; '
            'font-weight: bold; '
            'border: 1px solid black; '
            'background-color:lightcyan;'
            )

        self.btnStopAll = QPushButton()
        self.btnStopAll.setText("Stop All")
        self.btnStopAll.setObjectName("btnStopAll")
        self.btnStopAll.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
        self.btnStopAll.clicked.connect(self.stop_counting)
        self.btnStopAll.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; '
            'font-size: 13pt; '
            'color: blue; '
            'font-weight: bold; '
            'border: 1px solid black; '
            'background-color:lightcyan;'
            )

        self.btnResetAll = QPushButton()
        self.btnResetAll.setText("Reset All")
        self.btnResetAll.setObjectName("btnResetAll")
        self.btnResetAll.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
        self.btnResetAll.clicked.connect(self.resetAll)
        self.btnResetAll.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; '
            'font-size: 13pt; '
            'color: blue; '
            'font-weight: bold; '
            'border: 1px solid black; '
            'background-color:lightcyan;'
            )

        self.h_layout_1.addWidget(self.btnStartAll)
        self.h_layout_1.addWidget(self.btnStopAll)
        self.h_layout_1.addWidget(self.btnResetAll)

        self.layout.addLayout(self.h_layout_1)
        self.h_layout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self)     # Create Horizontal Layout for Middle Row

        # Creating Counter Labels
        #####################################
        self.counter_values = ['0', '1', '2']
        self.labels = {}
        for i in range(3):
            text = self.counter_values[i]

            self.labels[i] = QLabel(text)
            self.labels[i].setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.labels[i].setObjectName(text)
            self.labels[i].setStyleSheet(
                'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                'color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; '
                'font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid black;'
                )

            self.h_layout_2.addWidget(self.labels[i])

        self.layout.addLayout(self.h_layout_2)

        self.h_layout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self)     # Create Horizontal Layout for Bottom Row

        self.button_names_active = ['btnActive0', 'btnActive1', 'btnActive2']
        self.command_names_active = ('setActive0', 'setActive1', 'setActive2')

        self.buttons_active = {}

        for i, command_name_active in enumerate(self.command_names_active):
            self.buttons_active[i] = QPushButton()
            self.buttons_active[i].setText("Inactive")
            self.buttons_active[i].setObjectName(self.button_names_active[i])
            self.buttons_active[i].setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
            self.buttons_active[i].setCheckable(True)
            self.buttons_active[i].setStyleSheet(
                'font-family: Arial; '
                'font-size: 12pt; '
                'color: blue; '
                'background-color:lightcyan; '
                'font-weight: bold;'
                )

            self.buttons_active[i].clicked.connect(self.call_button_active_fun(i, command_name_active))
            self.h_layout_3.addWidget(self.buttons_active[i])

        self.layout.addLayout(self.h_layout_3)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Create timer object
        timer = QTimer(self)

        # Add a method with the timer
        timer.timeout.connect(self.start_counting)

        # Call start() method to modify the timer value
        timer.start(1000)

    def start_all(self):
        self.startCounting = True
        self.btnResetAll.setEnabled(False)

    def start_counting(self):
        if self.startCounting:
            for i in range(3):
                state = self.buttons_active[i].text()
                val_int = int(self.labels[i].text())

                if state == 'Active':
                    val_int += 1

                self.labels[i].setText(str(val_int))

    def stop_counting(self):
        self.startCounting = False
        self.btnResetAll.setEnabled(True)
        print('Counting stopped')

    def resetAll(self):
        for i in range(3):
            state = self.buttons_active[i].text()

            if state == 'Active':
                self.labels[i].setText('0')
    def call_button_active_fun(self, i, command_name):

        def button_active_fun():
            print(command_name)
            if command_name == self.command_names_active[i]:
                if self.buttons_active[i].clicked:
                    if self.buttons_active[i].text() == 'Inactive':
                        self.buttons_active[i].setText('Active')
                        self.buttons_active[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; '
                            'font-size: 12pt; '
                            'font-weight: bold; '
                            'color: blue; '
                            'background-color:lightgreen;')

                        self.labels[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                            'color: blue; background-color:orange; '
                            'font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid black;'
                            )

                    else:
                        self.buttons_active[i].setText('Inactive')
                        self.buttons_active[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; '
                            'font-size: 12pt; '
                            'font-weight: bold; '
                            'color: blue; '
                            'background-color:lightcyan;')

                        self.labels[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                            'color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; '
                            'font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid black;'
                            )

        return button_active_fun

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    # Intercept Exception, when they are not processed
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)

    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1) Eliminate the initial part of your post since it points out unnecessary things that are just noise, 2) I just want to focus on the underlying problem which is: how to test with relays? They do these tests, for simplicity let's say I have the relay on Pin 0, what should be sent to that pin0: a fixed value or a train of pulses? What pin should be read to check the status of the relay? Etc. Please do not talk to me about threads, which at the moment is not a solution until you explain how the relay test works.

Comment: As you wanted, I've changed the question and put new code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successful with solving of my problem, using threading.
I hope that someone who has the same problem as me can use my solution.

Explanation of my GUI:
There are three labels which show the content of three counters.
These counters can be startet by pushing the button StartAll and be stopped by StopAll.
They can be restartet again with StartAll.

The counters can only be startet after the Inactive button for each (desired) label is pushed and changed to Active.
During the counting process ResetAll button is disabled.
The counters must be stopped due to reset their content.
They have to be also Inactive to be reset.
Therefore the push buttons below the labels must be pushed to change to Inactive.

Here is the complete code of my working GUI.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Filename: 3_counter_Lastdauertester_using_tread.py
####################################################
# coding: utf-8
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

ACTIVE_WIDTH = 106
ACTIVE_HEIGHT = 32

class countingWorker(QObject):
    
    #explicit signal sent in the startCounting function
    signal_set_Label = pyqtSignal(dict, dict)

    #explicit slot that takes input from the signal_start_counting
    @pyqtSlot(dict, dict)
    def startCounting(self, value, state):
        
        value_emitted = {}
        for i in range(3):
            value_emitted[i] = int(value[i])

        while True:
            for j in range(3):
                if state[j] == 'Active':
                    value_emitted[j] += 1

            self.signal_set_Label.emit(value_emitted, state)
            time.sleep(1)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    
    #explicit signals from the start_counting_emitter function
    signal_start_counting = pyqtSignal(dict, dict)

    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()

        self.worker = countingWorker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        
        self.setFixedWidth(400)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.move(1100, 10)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test PYQT Signals")

        # Create the real GUI (MainWindow)
        ###############################################################
        self.createMainWindow()
    ###################################################################
    def createMainWindow(self):
    ###################################################################
        # Create Vertival layout for three Horizontal layouts
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # Create Horizontal Layout for Top Row
        self.h_layout_1 = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.btnStartAll = QPushButton()
        self.btnStartAll.setText("Start All")
        self.btnStartAll.setObjectName("btnStartAll")
        self.btnStartAll.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
        self.btnStartAll.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
            'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
            'background-color:lightcyan;')

        self.btnStopAll = QPushButton()
        self.btnStopAll.setText("Stop All")
        self.btnStopAll.setObjectName("btnStopAll")
        self.btnStopAll.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
        self.btnStopAll.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
            'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
            'background-color:lightcyan;')

        self.btnResetAll = QPushButton()
        self.btnResetAll.setText("Reset All")
        self.btnResetAll.setObjectName("btnResetAll")
        self.btnResetAll.setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
        self.btnResetAll.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnResetAll.setStyleSheet(
            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
            'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
            'background-color:lightcyan;')

        self.h_layout_1.addWidget(self.btnStartAll)
        self.h_layout_1.addWidget(self.btnStopAll)
        self.h_layout_1.addWidget(self.btnResetAll)

        # Add the Top Layout to the vertival layout
        self.layout.addLayout(self.h_layout_1)

        # Create Horizontal Layout for Middle Row
        self.h_layout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Creating Counter Labels
        #####################################
        self.counter_values = ['0', '1', '2']
        self.labels = {}
        for i in range(3):
            text = self.counter_values[i]

            self.labels[i] = QLabel(text)
            self.labels[i].setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.labels[i].setObjectName(text)
            self.labels[i].setStyleSheet(
                'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                'color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; '
                'font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid black;')

            self.h_layout_2.addWidget(self.labels[i])

        # Add the Middle Layout to the vertival layout
        self.layout.addLayout(self.h_layout_2)

        # Create Horizontal Layout for Bottom Row
        self.h_layout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.button_names_active = ['btnActive0', 'btnActive1', 'btnActive2']
        self.command_names_active = ('setActive0', 'setActive1', 'setActive2')

        self.buttons_active = {}

        for i, command_name_active in enumerate(self.command_names_active):
            self.buttons_active[i] = QPushButton()
            self.buttons_active[i].setText("Inactive")
            self.buttons_active[i].setObjectName(self.button_names_active[i])
            self.buttons_active[i].setFixedSize(ACTIVE_WIDTH, ACTIVE_HEIGHT)
            self.buttons_active[i].setCheckable(True)
            self.buttons_active[i].setStyleSheet(
                'font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; '
                'color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; '
                'font-weight: bold;')

            self.buttons_active[i].clicked.connect(self.call_button_active_fun(i, command_name_active))
            self.h_layout_3.addWidget(self.buttons_active[i])

        # Add the Bottom Layout to the vertival layout
        self.layout.addLayout(self.h_layout_3)

        # Set the whole Layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # making all of the connections
        self.btnStartAll.clicked.connect(self.start_counting_emitter)
        self.btnStopAll.clicked.connect(self.stop_counting)
        self.btnResetAll.clicked.connect(self.reset_all)
        self.worker.signal_set_Label.connect(self.set_Label_text)

    def start_counting_emitter(self):       
        self.signal_start_counting.connect(self.worker.startCounting)
        
        state = {}
        value = {}
        for i in range(3):
            state[i] = self.buttons_active[i].text()
            value[i] = self.labels[i].text()

        if not self.thread.isRunning():
            activity = []
            for j in range(3):
                activity.append(self.buttons_active[j].text())

            activities = (activity[0] == 'Inactive') and \
                         (activity[1] == 'Inactive') and \
                         (activity[2] == 'Inactive')

            if activities == False:
                self.btnStartAll.setCheckable(True)
                self.thread.start()
                print('thread started')

                self.btnStartAll.setEnabled(False)
                self.btnStartAll.setChecked(True)        
                self.btnStartAll.setStyleSheet(
                    'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                    'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
                    'background-color:lightgreen;')

                self.btnStopAll.setEnabled(True)
                
                self.btnResetAll.setEnabled(False)
                self.btnResetAll.setChecked(True)
                self.btnResetAll.setStyleSheet(
                    'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                    'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
                    'background-color:lightgreen;')
            
                self.signal_start_counting.emit(value, state)
        self.signal_start_counting.disconnect(self.worker.startCounting)

    # implicit slot of the stop buttons
    def stop_counting(self):       
        if self.thread.isRunning():
            self.thread.terminate()
            print('thread terminated')
            self.btnStartAll.setEnabled(True)
            self.btnStartAll.setChecked(False)
            self.btnStartAll.setStyleSheet(
                'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
                'background-color:lightcyan;')

            self.btnStopAll.setEnabled(False)
            
            self.btnResetAll.setEnabled(True)
            self.btnResetAll.setChecked(False)
            self.btnResetAll.setStyleSheet(
                'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                'color: blue; font-weight: bold; '
                'background-color:lightcyan;')

    def reset_all(self):
        for i in range(3):
            state = self.buttons_active[i].text()
            
            self.btnResetAll.setChecked(False)

            if state == 'Inactive':
                self.labels[i].setText('0')

    # explicit slot that takes input from the countingWorker
    # and sets the text of the provided box
    @pyqtSlot(dict, dict)
    def set_Label_text(self, labelText):
        for i in range(3):
            self.labels[i].setText(str(labelText[i]))

    def call_button_active_fun(self, i, command_name):
        def button_active_fun():
            print(command_name)
            if command_name == self.command_names_active[i]:
                if self.buttons_active[i].clicked:
                    if self.buttons_active[i].text() == 'Inactive':
                        self.buttons_active[i].setText('Active')
                        self.buttons_active[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; '
                            'font-weight: bold; color: blue; '
                            'background-color:lightgreen;')

                        self.labels[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                            'color: blue; background-color:orange; '
                            'font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid black;')

                    else:
                        self.buttons_active[i].setText('Inactive')
                        self.buttons_active[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; '
                            'font-weight: bold; color: blue; '
                            'background-color:lightcyan;')

                        self.labels[i].setStyleSheet(
                            'font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt; '
                            'color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; '
                            'font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid black;')

        return button_active_fun

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    # Intercept Exception, when they are not processed
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)

    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    exit(app.exec_())
```